# Is it possible with CE 1.7 or m2epro to retrieve the actual PayPal fees for a given order?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, paypal

I'm working on a net profit report with Magento CE 1.7 and m2epro and need to factor in the accurate cost of PayPal fees.  Ebay fees are similar, and for those I found the `getFinalFee()` method on `M2ePro/ebay_order`.

Is there an equivalent method for retrieving the PayPal fee amount, either in M2ePro or in the stock Magento PayPal integration?

Comment: I don't think this exists, because paypal rates depend on the payment method and the country of the merchant and customer. So you don't know before payment, what the fee will be - afaik

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt I'm actually looking for the fee once the order has been paid for.  It sounds like it's returned through the PayPal API, so I was hoping it was captured in Magento.

Comment: Ah ok. I just checked a few stores but I can't find any informations, even not sales_flat_order_payment.additional_information. But what you can try is to hook into the Paypal IPN Controller, log the requests and check them, if paypal sends this information, either va IPN or while backforwarding the customer to your page -> successAction

Answer (score 2):

Per the [PayPal IPN documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/), you should be able to grab the `payment_fee` parameter from the IPN response. You will then need to decide how you wish to persist this information (this will require a class rewrite I believe), and whether or not you want to make a specific report for it or just add it to an existing report (requiring another rewrite).